# How to draw a ray diagram for converging light onto diverging lens?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I'm working with drawing ray diagrams for different setups with lenses. In this case, I want to try and draw the ray diagram for a converging light onto a diverging lens. Suppose the setup is like this:

[image]

We can assume it has focal length of f. Can anyone walk me through the general step by step things to do in order to draw the ray diagrams after it has passed the diverging lens?